# Install pgAdmin 4 on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, postgresql, amazon-web-services, centos7, pgadmin-4

I'm working on setting up **PostgreSQL13** and **pgAdmin4** on Amazon Linux Workspace. It seems that Amazon Linux workspace is using Amazon Linux 2. The installation of PostgreSQL went really quick, but for pgAdmin4 I've been struggling for hours and without any success. Until now I've tried to folow the steps from the official page: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-rpm/ , but the issue that I've encounter is :

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from pgAdmin4: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/yum/redhat/rhel-2-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

, it seems that file does not exist on that repo. RedHat is suggesting:https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2850911 in cases like this to modify the **repo_gpgcheck** to 0  and through magic everything will work, but that was not the case for me. The repo_gpgcheck is for:
`` Either `1' or `0'. This tells yum whether or not it should perform a GPG signature check on the  repodata.  When this is set  in the [main] section it sets the default for all repositories. The default is `0'. ``

And if I'm doing a search through all existing repositories:
`sudo yum -v search pgadmin`, the only version found was **pgadmin3** in epel repo.

If someone managed to install pgAdmin4 on Amazon Linux 2, please share your secret. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried running pgadmin4 with docker? its seems from your experience like it would be much more simple and easy

Comment: Or, rather than installing it on the server, install it locally and point it at the Amazon instance?  Saves you maintenance in the long run and you don't need to install the X11 client libraries  ... you can always tunnel to the database through an `ssh` socks proxy if firewalling on the far end is a concern.

Comment: I just want to have installed pgAdmin4 on the Aws Linux workspace, because all development setUp is already there like: java, mvn,  postgreSQL , etc. I was thinking about running pgAdmin4 with docker, but it's more work for such a simple use case.. It's so frustrating, since I just need an IDE for the postgreSQL db. Maybe I'll try other IDEs like DBeaver. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I also tried AWS AMI 2 and ended giving up. In the end, I barely managed to get Ubuntu.

Comment: In my case I've ended up using Dbeaver instead of pgAdmin4.