# Install MySQL WorkBench on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: mysql-workbench, centos7, amazon-linux-2

After the mysql-server and other mysql libs have been installed on the Aws Linux machine, I wanted to install the Mysql WorkBench. Guess what ? It was a process full of failures..

Basically I've tried with multiple versions from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/ . I've tried with multiple 8.x.x, 6.x.x and 5.x.x. For newer versions like 8.x.x the errors were related to missing some libraries. I've tried to do a `sudo yum update`, but still those errors persisted.

After I've tried with older versions like 6.x.x and 5.x.x. The Workbench seemed to be installed correctly, but when I've tried to type `mysql-worbench`, the common error was:

```
/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustringC1ERKSs
```

Does anyone managed to installed it with success ? I remember that I had same issues with PgAdmin 4 here: [Install pgAdmin 4 on Amazon Linux 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108475/install-pgadmin-4-on-amazon-linux-2) . Basically in that case I gave up, and I used Dbeaver instead.

Really curios is someone managed to installed it. Thanks !